# How can i apply join into array of object inside array in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, join, aggregation-framework

How can i apply join into array of object inside array in MongoDb

Contact collection is like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("605ad4a19918f00008c54597"),
    "relatedTo" : [ 
        {
            "key" : "account",
            "value" : [ 
                ObjectId("605ad4a19918f00008c54595"), 
                ObjectId("6045ba60afc29100083ff6a9")
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "key" : "opportunity",
            "value" : [ 
                ObjectId("605ad4a19918f00008c54596"), 
                ObjectId("609124b67ab42c1f58b33935")
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Inside `relatredTo` array key is an collection name and value is an id which i need to foreign with

My Expected result is

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("605ad4a19918f00008c54597"),
    "relatedTo" : [ 
        {
            "key" : "account",
            "value" : [ 
                ObjectId("605ad4a19918f00008c54595"), 
                ObjectId("6045ba60afc29100083ff6a9")
            ],
            items: [
               account collection join result,
               account collection join result
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "key" : "opportunity",
            "value" : [ 
                ObjectId("605ad4a19918f00008c54596"), 
                ObjectId("609124b67ab42c1f58b33935")
            ],
            items: [
               opportunity collection join result,
               opportunity collection join result
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: i got your point, it is not possible to lookup collection through dynamic field.